# How can I open the file properties dialog on Windows via CLI?

Tags: windows, winapi

Does Windows offer a way to open the file/directory properties dialog through command line?

I found various `rundll32.dll` [commands](https://winaero.com/windows-10-rundll32-command-list/), but none of them offer this functionality. What would be the

[image]

Comment: Wow, I haven't checked powershell. This works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility called wmic in windows

`wmic datafile where Name="F:\\abc.txt" get Description,Name,FileType`

Hope it helps, Thnx in advance if not pls do comment below...

Comment: Thanks, but `wmic` is not available anymore on Windows 11 :-( I need a solution that works on Win10 and 11

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can utilize Powershell for this. Powershell is able to create COM objects, which some Windows APIs are implemented as, in particular the Windows shell. The Powershell command would be something like this:

```
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$shell.NameSpace($AbsolutePathToContainingFolder).ParseName($PathToFileInFolder).InvokeVerb("Properties")
```

Explaining the above:

1. The [`Shell`](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell).[`Application`](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-application) object exposes Windows shell methods you need here, it's an object of a [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) class
2. `$shell.NameSpace` is the method that gets you a "namespace" API object corresponding to the folder containing the file, to use for further calls
3. `$AbsolutePathToContainingFolder` denotes the full path to the folder containing the file you want to invoke the dialog on
4. `ParseName` is required to obtain a `FolderItem` object for the file
5. `$PathToFileInFolder` is [relative] path to the file in question
6. `InvokeVerb` is the method that through invoking a well, verb, opens a the Properties dialog

Documentation of all the methods is available to you navigating through the `Shell` object documentation linked above.